# React Router v6.4 (as per major update in official documentation): Child route component not updating when navigating from parent route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm encountering an issue with React Router v6 where a child route component () is not updating when navigating from a parent route (~diary) to the child route (~diary/list). Here's an overview of my setup:

**Route Configuration:**

index.tsx

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    children: [
      { path: "react", element: <React /> },
      {
        path: "diary",
        element: <Diary />,
        children: [{ path: "list", element: <List /> }],
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

**Components:**

diary.tsx

```
import { ReactElement } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const Diary = (): ReactElement => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Welcome to Express Diary</h2>
      <p>Record your diary life</p>
      <button onClick={() => navigate("/diary/list")}>
        Open your Express Diary
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

list.tsx

```
import { ReactElement } from "react";

export const List = (): ReactElement => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>This is the Diary List!</h3>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Issue:**

When navigating from ~diary to ~diary/list, the URL changes correctly, but the  component does not update/render. There are no errors in the console, and navigation logic seems correct. I've ensured that all components are correctly imported, and there are no conflicts with styles or components.

**Expected Behavior:**

When navigating from ~diary to ~diary/list, I expect the  component to update/render according to the route change.

Comment: Do you want to render diary and list components at the same time when the user stays in "diary/list" route?